# Find the number of sequences with 6 letters from the set {, , , }, where  appears an even number, and  appears an odd number of times.

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

We denote by $_6$ the number of sequences with 6 letters from the set {, , , }, where  appears an even number of times, and  appears an odd number of times.

(a) (True / False): $_6$ is the coefficient of $^6$ in the expression

$
(1 + ^2 + ^4 + ^6 + ⋯ )( + ^3 + ^5 + ⋯ )(1 +  + ^2 + ^3 + ⋯ )^2
$

(b) (True / False): $_6$ is the coefficient of $\frac{^6}{6!}$ in the expression

$(1 + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} + \frac{x^6}{6!}+ \cdots)\cdot (x + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!}+ \cdots)\cdot \left(1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!}+ \cdots \right)^2$

(c) (True / False): $_6$ is the coefficient of $\frac{^6}{6!}$ in the expression

$(1 + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} + \frac{x^6}{6!})\cdot (x + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!})\left(1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} +\frac{x^6}{6!}\right)^2$

(d) (True / False): $_6$ is the coefficient of $\frac{^6}{6!}$ in the expression

$(1 + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!})\cdot (x + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!}+\frac{x^7}{7!})\left(1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} +\frac{x^6}{6!}\right)^2$

So (a) is wrong because we have distinct letters where we don't care about the order, so we have an exponential generating function. But where it gets tricky is (d), because I believe that we get, for the first e.g.f., the terms until $x^4/4!$, because we can have a maximum of 4 A's in order to have an odd number of B's and the term $x^7/7!$ in the second e.g.f. is irrelevant for counting the number of sequences with 6 letters. But if my assumption is wrong and (d) is False then (b) and (c) is correct. Can somebody tell me which is the correct answer?

Comment: Consider... what is the coefficient of $x^2$ in $(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)^2$?  What is the coefficient of $x^2$ in $(1+x+x^2)^2$?  What is the coefficient of $x^2$ in $(1+x+x^2+x^3+\dots)^2$?  Does the inclusion of additional terms of higher power than we care about actually change anything?

Comment: The punchline is that although the coefficient of, say, $x^{20}$ may be different for the answers to (b),(c), and (d)... the coefficient of $x^6$ (*and thus of $\frac{x^6}{6!}$*) will be the same for each of these.  Could you be more strict and not include any terms in any of the parentheses which will not contribute to the overall coefficient of $x^6$?  Sure... but it is unnecessary to worry about this.  All three of (b),(c),(d) are true and correct.